# Fragments instance saved issue

Tags: android, json, eclipse

I am working on drawer layout fragments with view pager and showing the data in grid view but the problem occurs when i open the same fragment again then it shows blank. I am using viewpager page strips in fragments. I dont know whats the problem. Is anyone there who can help me.

Comment: post your code so that we can find some clue from that

Comment: See here...... - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941400/view-pager-fragments-issue